# TikZ draw command mistake with two dashes and confusing results

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-styles

I made a silly mistake in my TikZ code and fixed it but I still don't know why so I'll post my question here.

First assume that I generate something with an arrow in background like this.

```
\documentclass[border={10mm}]{standalone}
\usepackage[american,siunitx,RPvoltages]{circuitikz}
\usetikzlibrary {shapes.misc}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.markings, arrows.meta} 
\usetikzlibrary{backgrounds}
\usetikzlibrary {shadows,shapes.symbols}
\usetikzlibrary{external}
\tikzexternalize 


\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[
]


\begin{scope}[on background layer, very thick ] 
\draw[ultra thick, red!50,  -{Stealth[scale=0.8]}] --(1,0) -- ( 3,0) ;
\end{scope}

\end{tikzpicture}


\end{document}
```

Please note that I made a mistake by adding two dashes before the `(1,0)` as `--(1,0)`.
However, the compilation is still okay on Overleaf without error and the arrow looks good on the Overleaf PDF panel.

[image]

However, if you save it as PDF and open it with a PDF reader such as Forxit Reader or Adobe Acrobat Reader you would see that the arrow is not displayed properly. I don't actually know why.

[image]

And even more confusing, if you save the PDF above as `arrow.pdf` (the arrow with head only) and the include in a document like below, the compilation is still OK and the arrow PDF from panel on Overleaf looks good. But again if you download the PDF, you would still see that the arrow isn't displayed properly.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}


\begin{document}
 \includegraphics[]{arrow.pdf}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I simplified your example a bit

```
\ExplSyntaxOn 
\sys_ensure_backend:
\pdf_uncompress:
\ExplSyntaxOff 
\documentclass[border={10mm},tikz]{standalone}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw[ultra thick, red!50,->] -- (1,0) -- ( 3,0) ; %or (1,0)--(3,0)
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

If one compile that with and without the faulty dashes and then compare the PDF's then the only difference is at the begin of the path construction where the faulty PDF uses an `l` instead of a `m` operator:

With the dashes:

```
1.0 0.5 0.5 rg 1.0 0.5 0.5 RG
28.3468 0.0 l 
83.83492 0.0 l
```

Without the dashes

```
1.0 0.5 0.5 rg 1.0 0.5 0.5 RG
28.3468 0.0 m 
83.83492 0.0 l
```

According to the PDF specification a subpath must begin with `m` or `re`:

> The path construction operators may be invoked in any sequence, but the first one invoked must be m or re to begin a new subpath.

Adobe reader therefore ignores the subpath (the next subpath with the arrow tip has an `m` in both cases) but it looks as if the PDF viewer of overleaf is not so strict and handles the `l` like an `m`.

Comment: Nice, it's over my head though. How would you show the path constructions like that?

Comment: simply open the uncompressed PDF in some editor.